# Unable to register MBean interceptor.WireTap, javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty

Tags: spring-integration

I was getting the below error when I enabled WireTap interceptor for one of the channels. The OotB WireTap interceptor was not loading, and throwing the below exception during server startup. The spring-integration version was 3.x

> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader (ContextLoader.java:319) - Context initialization failed
>        [java] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exporter' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap@5596e217] with key 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0'; nested exception is javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
>        [java]     at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:50)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
>        [java]     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>        [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>        [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>        [java] Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap@5596e217] with key 'org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0'; nested exception is javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
>        [java]     at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:602)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:527)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
>        [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
>        [java]     ... 26 more

Answer (score 0):

I think this error happens in spring-integration v3. Below is how I resolved it.

- Create a custom class extending WireTap, define the spring bean.
- Use ManagedResource annotation to provide the name, this should match spring bean name.
- Add the interceptor to channel that needs to be tapped.

Post this, I was able to tap the channel successfully.

You  don't need override any method in the custom class, just add the constructors similar to WireTap class. In simple words, I created my own interceptor class and used it to tap the channel.

> `@ManagedResource(objectName = "com.xyz.channel.interceptor:name=wireTapExtended")
>   public class WireTapExtended extends WireTap`

```
<int:channel id="channelIdToTap">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:ref bean="wireTapExtended" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<bean id="wireTapExtended" name="wireTapExtended" class="com.xyz.channel.interceptor.WireTapExtended">
    <constructor-arg name="channel" ref="channelIdToTap" />
</bean>
```

I see this is only MBean config

```
<bean id="jmxExporterSite" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false"> <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" /> <property name="registrationBehaviorName" value="REGISTRATION_REPLACE_EXISTING"/> <property name="beans"> <map> <entry key="SpringBeans:name=hibernateStatisticsMBeanSite" value-ref="hibernateStatisticsMBeanSite" /> <entry key="SpringBeans:name=ehCacheManagerMBean" value-ref="cacheManager" /> </map> </property> </bean>
```

Comment: Interesting... Would be great to see your config for the `MBeanExporter` to try to reproduce in the current version. Although that looks like the `ObjectNamingStrategy` there returns `null`. Although really Spring Integration `3.0` is ancient...

Comment: The code in comments isn't readable. You should use edit for your question